# Calculating dawn and sunset times using PyEphem

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

Is it possible to calculate Dawn, Dusk, and sunset times using [PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/)? I've used PyEphem to produce day and night time, but I didn't find anything on sunset/dusk/dawn

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For ***dawn amd dusk***, see [**pyephem documentation regarding twilight**](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/rise-set.html#computing-twilight)
In a nutshell, dawn and dusk express the time when *the center* of the Sun is at a particular angle below the horizon; the angle used for this calculation varies for the definition of the "civilian", navigation (nautical) and astronomical twilights which use 6, 12 and 18 degrees respectively.

In opposition the ***sunrise*** corresponds to the time when *the edge* of the Sun appears (or disappears, for sunset) just above/below the horizon (0 degree).  Hence everybody, civilians, sailors and astronomy enthusiasts alike get the same  rise/set times.  (see [**Naval Observatory risings and settings** in pyephem documentation](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/rise-set.html#naval-observatory-risings-and-settings)).

**To summarize**, once one has properly parametrized an `pyephem.Observer` (setting its lat, long, date, time, pressure (? for altitude?),  etc.), the various twilight times (dawn, dusk) and the sunrise and sunset times are obtained from the
 `Observer.previous_rising()` and `Observer.next_setting()` methods,
    whereby
    the first argument is `ephem.Sun()` and 
    the `use_center=` argument needs to be set to `True` for twilight calculations, and
    the horizon is either 0 (or 0:34 if you account for refraction of the atmosphere) or -6, -12 or -18.

Answer (score 32):

The following script will calculate sunrise, sunset, and twilight times using PyEphem. The comments should be adequate to explain what each part is doing.

```
import ephem

#Make an observer
fred      = ephem.Observer()

#PyEphem takes and returns only UTC times. 15:00 is noon in Fredericton
fred.date = "2013-09-04 15:00:00"

#Location of Fredericton, Canada
fred.lon  = str(-66.666667) #Note that lon should be in string format
fred.lat  = str(45.95)      #Note that lat should be in string format

#Elevation of Fredericton, Canada, in metres
fred.elev = 20

#To get U.S. Naval Astronomical Almanac values, use these settings
fred.pressure= 0
fred.horizon = '-0:34'

sunrise=fred.previous_rising(ephem.Sun()) #Sunrise
noon   =fred.next_transit   (ephem.Sun(), start=sunrise) #Solar noon
sunset =fred.next_setting   (ephem.Sun()) #Sunset

#We relocate the horizon to get twilight times
fred.horizon = '-6' #-6=civil twilight, -12=nautical, -18=astronomical
beg_twilight=fred.previous_rising(ephem.Sun(), use_center=True) #Begin civil twilight
end_twilight=fred.next_setting   (ephem.Sun(), use_center=True) #End civil twilight
```

Relocating the horizon accounts for light refracting around the curvature of the Earth. PyEphem has the capability to calculate this more exactly given a temperature and pressure, but the U.S. Naval Astronomical Almanac prefers to ignore the atmosphere and simply relocate the horizon. I refer to the USNAA here because it's an authoritative source against which these sorts of calculations can be checked. You can also check answers on [NOAA's website](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/).

Note that PyEphem takes and returns values in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time. This means that you have to convert your local time to UTC and then convert UTC back to local time to find the answers you're probably looking for. On the date I wrote this answer Fredericton, Canada, in the [ADT timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_Time_Zone) was 3 hours behind UTC.

For kicks, I've also thrown in a calculation of solar noon. Note that this is an additional hour off from what you'd expect - that's a side-effect of our using daylight savings time.

All this returns:

```
begin civil twilight: 2013/9/4 09:20:46
sunrise:              2013/9/4 09:51:25
noon:                 2013/9/4 16:25:33
sunset:               2013/9/4 22:58:49
end civil twilight:   2013/9/4 23:29:22
```

Note that we'd have to subtract 3 hours to convert them to the ADT timezone.

[This](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/rise-set.html) PyEphem documentation page contains much of the above, though I've tried to both clarify points I found confusing and include the important parts of that link here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to set the `horizon` parameter [below the horizon](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#observer-horizon) according to the different definitions of dusk/dawn.